# How to scroll UIPageViewController on top of UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have this really strange scenario. There's a `UIPageViewController` on top of `UIPageViewController`. And then the upper one is on the section where it's clear view, I would like to be able to swipe and use the `UIPageViewController` that is underneath. Sliding through pages on upper `UIPageViewController` is done with menu buttons.

It's something like :

[x][x][x][x]

[x][ ][x]

I've tried using

```
func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {}
```

But I cant seem to differentiate between what to return...

Any ideas, if there's any other way?

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Not getting what you want, maybe add some image to show?

Comment: If it's not User-Interactive - you're changing its appearance / content via buttons - does the "overlay" object *need* to be a `UIPageViewController`?

Comment: Yeah. it must. ;/ And one more thing, the both page view controllers have the same parent view controller. But one is in front of the other.

Comment: Well... I *could* be incorrect, but as far as I know, you cannot display 3 pages at a time in a `UIPageViewController`, which is what you'd have to do accomplish the layout you're describing. Think you might need to reevaluate your approach / design.... unless... if the idea is that the "overlay" VC would show a wide Page, where the center is transparent and it just *looks* like 3 elements?